# Distinguishing between quoted and non-quoted phrases within a string in VB.NET

Tags: string, vb.net, split

Say I have a string from a user input that includes both quoted and non-quoted elements:

```vb
cmdArgs = "write "Hello, world" 10"
```

Is there a feasible way to `Split()` this into *three* separate strings `write`, `Hello, world`, and `10`? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you try: `Dim vals() As String = cmdArgs.Split(Convert.ToChar(""""))`

Comment: You could use a `TextFieldParser` and specify the space as the delimiter. It will handle quoted values automatically.

Comment: BTW, you actually mean `cmdArgs = "write ""Hello, world"" 10"`, because quotes must be escaped in VB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I found a suitable workaround by creating a separate array that measures `cmdArgs` with a separate delimiter (thanks, Andrew Mortimer!). If the original array exceeds a certain length, it will defer to the new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `TextFieldParser` to read delimited text containing quoted values:

```vb
Dim str = "write ""Hello, world"" 10"

Using reader As New StringReader(str),
      parser As New TextFieldParser(reader) With {.Delimiters = {" "}}
    Dim fields = parser.ReadFields()

    For Each field In fields
        Console.WriteLine(field)
    Next
End Using
```

Output:

```
write
Hello, world
10
```